# Are RSS guids actually expected to be _globally_ unique?

Tags: rss

Just trying to clear up what level of uniqueness the `<guid>` element in an RSS feed is actually supposed to have.  I understand that one of its main purposes is to be something that software can use to identify the item for such purposes as read/unread tracking.  But am I right that:

- once a guid has been used, it should never be used again, even if the last instance was removed from the feed ages ago?
- it should be unique not only within a feed, but also across multiple feeds and even (to the extent it can be achieved) unrelated websites?
- one of the reasons it's common to use URLs as guids is to help achieve the above?

Moreover, if a program *does* encounter the same guid twice in different feeds, what should happen?

- it treats them as distinct RSS items, since they are in different feeds?
- they are considered to be one and the same item, just published in multiple places (similar to Usenet crossposts)?
- it depends on whether they're on the same site/domain?
- the behaviour is undefined?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's a good question and the answer is No.

It was a bad choice of terminology.

The guids only have to be unique to the feed.

The goal in adding them was to have a way for an aggregator to know for sure whether or not it's seen the item before. A locally-unique id suffices for that purpose.

Comment: upvoted! if I wanted to get a unique id across different feeds, what would I use then? link in combination with guid? link only? guid only (what happens to the ones without a guid here)